# Export/Import of DNN site

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9, dnn9

I have a website currently running on DNN 3. I want to do an export of this DNN 3 site and import it onto a website running on DNN 9.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible, maybe, but extremely unlikely that it will be a simple process.

Your best option might be to attempt an upgrade of that DNN3 site to DNN 9.

That or just pay someone to manually recreate the pages and copy/paste content. That might even be the cheapest option :D

Answer (score 0):

Sadly at this point in time this will not be possible, the templates/process for export/import have changed between the versions of DNN and it would not be a trusted or reliable process to do so.

I would second Chris' recommendation regarding just re-create the site, as most likely the modules in use etc are no longer viable.

Answer (score 0):

As Mitchel and Chris already noted, the answer is no. Depending on the size of your site, I would either recreate it from scratch, maybe cou can export/import the content of one or another module and get it up and running in a reasonable time frame.
If the site is really big (and that depends on the number of pages, modules, users,...) it could be better to take some money and hire someone to help. Maybe it is possible to find an upgrade path.